# kid3 - Import Album Art along with other tags from Discogs

Tags: tags, metadata, mp3

(I'm brand-new to kid3, and I'm using the GUI version rather than CLI. )

I'm trying to finally organize my mp3 collection, most of which have an artist and title, but no album name. Since I don't know off the top of my head what album any particular track is from, I've been using the Import from Discogs function of kid3 to look up the album information, then apply the tags from that album to the .mp3. Everything works great, except that the album art does not get tagged in the .mp3 file. I can see the path to the discogs image, but it does not get applied to the .mp3. I can grab the album art manually (using the search function and drag-and-drop), but it's an extra step, multiplied by thousands of tracks, so I'd much rather it be done automatically with the rest of the tags.

For reference, I'm coming from mp3tag, which does exactly what I want, but the interface of kid3 seems to be superior so far, so I'd like to make it work.